# How to transpose rows into tables

Tags: google-sheets

I have some data that, for 'record keeping,' fits nicely on a row.  However, I would like to take that data, broken into three groups of 10 cells each (so 30 columns total), and convert it into an easy to read 'table' of sorts.  After a couple of empty rows, repeat the process with the next record (row) of data.

This isn't a case of choosing and seeing one at a time, but rather, viewing all by scrolling up and down.

I've tried using transpose, however, I can figure out how to get it to only show one data-row at a time.  Maybe there's a different function that would do the same thing but differently enough?

To make it simple and without a need to see any actual examples, just have a few rows with 30 columns, in three groups of 10 cells each (so there is no mismatched size).  The first group contains type A information, second contains type B, third type C.  When converted on a different sheet for easy viewing, group A shows in 10 rows in one column, with groups B and C next to it, then a couple of rows down, repeat.

Is there a way to do this without using a script of some sort?

Edit:
[image: Part of the source material]

[image: Example of desired output]

I'm not worried about it looking fancy (I can work on that after the fact).  It's simple trying to get it so that one line is transposed into a table, then a couple of lines down, the next row is transposed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<List<String>> transpose(List<List<String>> table) {
    List<List<String>> ret = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    final int N = table.get(0).size();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        List<String> col = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (List<String> row : table) {
            col.add(row.get(i));
        }
        ret.add(col);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are more valuable and more likely to attract upvotes.